# Consulta en campo de una misma tabla Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Estoy trabajando el Laravel 5.5.

Tengo una tabla que se llama servidores, En esta tabla inserto servidores tanto fisicos como virtuales, y los identifico a traves del siguiente campo.

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_uso', 'Uso', [0 => 'Escoge una opción'] + App\Usos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'listaUsos', 'class'=>'chosen']) !!}
```

Y Tengo otro campo que se llama Servidor Padre, que me lista los servidores que hay en la misma tabla.

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 'Servidor padre', App\Servidores::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen']) !!}
```

El problema es, que si en el campo Uso se escoge la opción Virtual, En el campo Servidor Padre deberia listar unicamente el nombre de los servidores que figuran como Fisicos.

Alguien me podria indicar como hacerlo ?

[image: Descripción]
Intente hacer un CONCAT, para que al momento de escoger el valor de la lista desplegable, trajera el ID de si es fisico o virtual, para poder identificarlo, pero pues claramente no es practico, y me gustaria aprender como hacer esa consulta en especial.

Comment: Para selects dinámicos sería mejor que ocupes angular o algún framework de javascript de tu preferencia, por último jquery.  Pero si quieres hacer un select con blade creo que lo ideal sería que no necesites que sea dinámico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leyendo la documentación pude agregar el `where` a la lista que estaba haciendo, y me quedo así:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
               'Servidor padre:', 
 App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(hostname, ' - ', id_uso) AS 
                 hostname_version"), "id")                                
                 ->where('id_uso', '=', 1)
                 -> pluck('hostname_version', 'id')
                 ->toArray(), null, 
 ['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;', 
  'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

Esta opción sirve para la condición y adicionalmente el `CONCAT`, por si a alguien le pueda servir.

En caso de que unicamente se quiera el valor de la columna, lo hice así:

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
               'Servidor padre:', 
 App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("hostname AS hostname"), "id")
                ->where('id_uso', '=', 1)
                ->pluck('hostname', 'id')
                ->toArray(), null, 
 ['required','class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;', 
  'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

[image: Des]

Ahí se puede ver unicamente me aparecen los que son servidores fisicos.

Comment: recuerda que si esta respuesta a tu propia pregunta, resuleve el problema debes marcarla como aceptada para que a otros usuarios les sirva cuando la consulten, mientras yo te doy un +1

Comment: No lo sabia, y te agraadezco por la información, me dice que hasta dentro de dos días se puede dar esa solución.

Gracias Alfredo